# Highcharts - do not return empty rows from the table

Tags: mysql, charts, highcharts

Both charts connect to the db ok, no errors.  It's the data that is returned in container1 [6,2] and container2 [6,2]  The 6 is the number of empty rows and the 2 is the rows with data in them.

Question: How do I change the code to only return keys that make the lower bar data=2?

With the help of a php book I got I've been able to figure out what the code does, what I don't have is the skill to do is change the code.  Anything I've tried just kills the entire chart.

Thanks greatly for any help anyone can send my way.  And...all the best for this holiday season!

[image: two bars when lower only is correct]
<sub>(source: [tillsonburgonline.com](http://tillsonburgonline.com/temp/chart.jpg))</sub>

```
xAxis: {
categories: [<?php
$aneskeys = array_keys($anes);
print "'$aneskeys[0]'";
for ($a = 1; $a < count($aneskeys); $a++) {
print ", '$aneskeys[$a]'";
}
   ?>],         
  },        

yAxis: {                          
allowDecimals: false 
},
plotOptions: {
series: {
pointWidth: 10,                     
}
},  
series: [{
    //name: '',
color: '#FF0000',
shadow: true,
borderColor: '',
data: [<?php
$aneskeys = array_keys($anes);
$anest = $anes[$aneskeys[0]];
print "$anest";
for ($a = 1; $a < count($anes); $a++) {
$anest = $anes[$aneskeys[$a]];
print ", $anest";
   }
 ?>]
     }],
    });
 });
</script>
<div id="container1" style="width:100%; height:200px;"></div>
</div>

<div>
<?php


xAxis: {
categories: [<?php
$anatkeys = array_keys($anat);
print "'$anatkeys[0]'";
for ($b = 1; $b < count($anatkeys); $b++) {
print ", '$anatkeys[$b]'";
      }
    ?>],                     
   },       

yAxis: {                          
allowDecimals: false                  
},
plotOptions: {
series: {
pointWidth: 10,             
}
},  
series: [{
 name: 'Anatomy',
 color: '#FF0000',
 shadow: true,
 borderColor: '',
data: [<?php
 $anatkeys = array_keys($anat);
 $anato = $anat[$anatkeys[0]];
 print "$anato";
for ($b = 1; $b < count($anat); $b++) {
 $anato = $anat[$anatkeys[$b]];
 print ", $anato";
   }
      ?>]
    }],
  });
});
```

Comment: Er... I think you'll need to be a bit more specific as to what chart library you're using.

Comment: Solved the problem. This is the solution. $result = mysqli_query($con, "SELECT * FROM wp_gfsept2013 WHERE anesthesiology = 'anesthesiology'");

Answer (score 0):

You can use last element from array instead of using for loop. But better will be separate php code and javascript. Both scirpts connect by json.

Comment: thanks sebastian, I found another way to put multiple charts on one page here on SOF.  What I can't do is get the charts to only have one bar - the one with data in the table and not return the number of empty cells and put them in the chart as the top bar.